# How to deal with JAXB ComplexType with MixedContent data?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc

**I got this XML structure:**

```
<Tax>
  <Money currency="USD">0.00</Money>
  <Description xml:lang="en">
     17.5% Non-Recoverable
    <ShortName>vatspecial</ShortName>
  </Description>
</Tax>
```

**Notice that `Description` node has `MixedContent` *(composed with text and XML)* and this is the `XSD` part regarding `Description` node**:

```
<xsd:complexType name="TaxDescriptionType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="ShortName" type="xsd:string" />
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute ref="xml:lang" />
</xsd:complexType>
```

**Everything is ok at this point, `XJC` outputs the generated classes like this one regarding `TaxDescriptionType`:**

```
package org.com.project;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.CollapsedStringAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

/**
 * <p>Java class for TaxDescriptionType complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="TaxDescriptionType">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="ShortName" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *       &lt;attribute ref="{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang"/>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "TaxDescriptionType", propOrder = {
    "shortName"
})
public class TaxDescriptionType {

    @XmlElement(name = "ShortName", required = true)
    protected String shortName;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "lang", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "NCName")
    protected String lang;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the shortName property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getShortName() {
        return shortName;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the shortName property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setShortName(String value) {
        this.shortName = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the lang property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getLang() {
        return lang;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the lang property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setLang(String value) {
        this.lang = value;
    }

}
```

**Then, with the above `class` I am able to work around with the elements like this:**

```
taxDescriptionType.setLang("en");
taxDescriptionType.setShortName("vatspecial");
/* missing value: 17.5% Non-Recoverable */
```

**But the problem is that I can't found a way to `get` or `set` the `17.5% Non-Recoverable` text of the `MixedContent-ComplexType` from the above `XML` example.**

---

**This is what I tried and it's not working:**

- Used `mixed="true"` attribute like this:

`<xsd:complexType name="TaxDescriptionType" mixed="true">`

***(I think XJC is ignoring the last attribute)***

---

**Doing some research, I found this:**

[JAXB XJC compiler disregarding mixed=true on XML Schema documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049067/jaxb-xjc-compiler-disregarding-mixed-true-on-xml-schema-documents)

But I am not sure if this is the way to solve this. One of the answers said that this is a bug and in the other one shows a code that transforms the `MixedContent` into a `List<Serializable>` and maybe the next situation will be about how to deal with this:

```
taxDescriptionType.getContent().add(Serializable element);
```

***(And I really don't know how to deal with a `Serializable` element)***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you mentioned you need to add the `mixed` attribute to indicate that your type supports mixed content.  Without this specified your XML content is invalid:

```
<xsd:complexType name="TaxDescriptionType" mixed="true">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="ShortName" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute ref="xml:lang" />
</xsd:complexType>
```

The generated `TaxDescriptionType` class will have the following property.  Essentially this means that all of the non-attribute content will be stored in a `List`.  This is necessary because you need a mechanism that indicates where the text nodes are wrt the element content.

```
@XmlElementRef(name = "ShortName", namespace = "http://www.example.org/schema", type = JAXBElement.class)
@XmlMixed
protected List<Serializable> content;
```

You will populate this list with instances of `String` (representing text nodes) and `JAXBElement` (representing element content).

---

**ALTERNATIVELY**

Mixed content generally makes life more complicated than it needs to be.  If possible I would recommend an alternate XML representation.

```
<Tax>
  <Money currency="USD">0.00</Money>
  <Description xml:lang="en" ShortName="vatspecial">
    17.5% Non-Recoverable
  </Description>
</Tax>
```

Or

```
<Tax>
  <Money currency="USD">0.00</Money>
  <Description xml:lang="en">
    <LongName>17.5% Non-Recoverable</LongName>
    <ShortName>vatspecial</ShortName>
  </Description>
</Tax>
```

Comment: Is the `Serializable` type parameter of `List` is significant?

Answer (score 2):

With mixed=true, in ObjectFactory there should be a function like `JAXBElement<ShortNameType> createTaxDescriptionTypeShortNameType(ShortNameType)`, which generates the serializable element for you.

```
 @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "shortnametype", scope = TaxDescriptionType.class)
    public JAXBElement<ShortNameType> createTaxDescriptionTypeShortNameType(ShortNameType value) {
        return new JAXBElement<ShortNameType>(new QName("", "shortnametype"), ShortNameType.class, TaxDescriptionType.class, value);
 }
```