# Missing value for XmlElement

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I should read every value of Turn element in the input XML:

```
<Section type="report" startTime="0" endTime="182.952">
        <Turn speaker="spk1" startTime="7.186" endTime="8.114">
            <Sync time="7.186"/>un souci avec une inscription
        </Turn>
        <Turn speaker="spk2" startTime="8.114" endTime="8.533">
            <Sync time="8.114"/>ouais
        </Turn>
        <Turn speaker="spk1 spk2" startTime="8.533" endTime="9.731">
            <Sync time="8.533"/>
            <Who nb="1"/>first value!
            <Who nb="2"/>second value!
        </Turn>
</Section>
```

So I used JAXB and made the following classes:

Section:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Section")
public class Section {

private List<Turn> turn;

@XmlElement(name="Turn")
public List<Turn> getTurn() {
    if(turn == null){
        turn = new ArrayList<Turn>();
    }
    return turn;
}

public void setTurn(List<Turn> turn) {
    this.turn = turn;
}
}
```

Turn:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Turn")
public class Turn {

private String speaker;
private float startTime;
private float endTime;
private Sync sync;
private String content;
private List<Who> whoList;

@XmlAttribute
public String getSpeaker() {
    return speaker;
}
public void setSpeaker(String speaker) {
    this.speaker = speaker;
}
public float getStartTime() {
    return startTime;
}

@XmlAttribute
public void setStartTime(float startTime) {
    this.startTime = startTime;
}

@XmlAttribute
public float getEndTime() {
    return endTime;
}
public void setEndTime(float endTime) {
    this.endTime = endTime;
}

@XmlValue
public String getContent() {
    return content;
}
public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}
}
```

But when I want to read for example the value of Turn where speaker equals "spk1 spk2", the method `getContent` of Turn return only "second value!".. How i can get all content with "first value!" ?
I know is not allowed to set XmlElement with XmlValue for one Element, but I have no choice, the xml files are like that, and I should work with many files like that..

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you deal with mixed content. Have a look to the other question [how-to-deal-with-jaxb-complextype-with-mixedcontent-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568247/how-to-deal-with-jaxb-complextype-with-mixedcontent-data) and [jaxb-xmlmixed-usage-for-reading-xmlvalue-and-xmlelement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940267/jaxb-xmlmixed-usage-for-reading-xmlvalue-and-xmlelement). It would be manageable with the annotation `@XmlMixed` for your `Turn` class. Then, I'm not quite sure if you need the getter and setter methods for the content.

Comment: Nice ! i make a new attribute list with @XmlMixed, then it return all my content !
Thanks Loic M.

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem comes from your declaration of `@XmlElement(name="Turn")`. If you have a look to the following [tutorial from Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html), you'll see he is using a wrapper for its list thanks to the annotation `XmlElementWrapper` and sets the annotations at the declaration of the list, not before the method, as following:

> // XmLElementWrapper generates a wrapper element around XML representation
> @XmlElementWrapper(name = "bookList")
>
> // XmlElement sets the name of the entities
> @XmlElement(name = "book")
> private ArrayList bookList;

In your case, I think JAXB manage an object when you expect it to deal with a list of objects.

Comment: JAXB manage a really list of objects, because, when i load my xml, getTurn() return a List of Turn like this for the previous example:
0:Turn with content equals: "un souci avec une inscription"
1:Turn with content equals:"ouais"
2:Turn with content equals:"second value!" Here the first value is missing..

Comment: OK, I first didn't get the point that the value of the Turn element is splited with your `Who` elements. Quite strange. Are you sure the definition of your input XML make sense?

Comment: No, rather sure they are false, but they are not mine, i must work with it .