# JAXB Java module

Tags: java, xml, parsing, generics, jaxb

Can anyone help me out with my problem for writing a JAXB java modules from XML
Sample XML is as below. The issue I am having is with the Attribute class I am writing. In the XML you can see that the tag  can be repeatable and has values. So if I put the List attribute, how can I fetch the value as well.

```
<top>
<attribute name="root">
<attribute name="a">
<attribute name="b">abValue</attribute>
<attribute name="d">
<attribute name="e">eValue</attribute>
</attribute>
</attribute>
<attribute name="c">cValue</attribute>
</attribute>
</top>
```

---

For human readability, here is formatted version:

```
<top>
    <attribute name="root">
        <attribute name="a">
            <attribute name="b">abValue</attribute>
            <attribute name="d">
                <attribute name="e">eValue</attribute>
            </attribute>
        </attribute>
        <attribute name="c">cValue</attribute>
    </attribute>
</top>
```

I have been referred to
[How to deal with JAXB ComplexType with MixedContent data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568247/how-to-deal-with-jaxb-complextype-with-mixedcontent-data)
However If you see the  tag will not contain both Value and XML at the same time. Either it will be a List or have value.

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Top {

    List<Attribute> attribute;

}
```

I am having the issue with my Attribute class. I have no wsdl. I want a xml to be generated from the Java object after I do some pre-processing on it based upon the name attribute within every  tag. It depends upon the values I fetch from the database.

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

public class Attribute {

    @XmlAttribute(name="name")
    String name;

    List<Attribute> attribute;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I like your element name "attribute" but that is just me.  it looks to me like you basically have a top level item `top` which contains one `attribute` element. Each `attribute` element can contain either a list of `attribute` elements or a value. Is this correct?

Comment: yes. I want to write a Java class which can used in JAXB for marshalling and unmarshalling. The main thing is that a tag <attribute> can have a list of attributes or it can be leaf node as well. So List<Attribute> can be used but the value of it how this can be incorporated.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the slow response. Before we look at the JaxB class structure, please can I ask you to talk through the data that the xml represents. Thanks in advance. Martin