# Single Tag XML to multiple fields JAXB

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, jaxb

I have the following problem, with JAXB library.

XML

```
<par>
   <name>content</name>
   <value>This is a value</value>
</par>
<par>
    <name>map</name>
    <value>
      <info>
         <obj>obj1</obj>
      </info>
    </value>
</par>
```

Class Java

```
public static class Par {

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    private Info valueObject;

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    private Node valueString;
}

public static class Info {

    @XmlElement(name = "obj")
    private String obj;
}
```

the problem is that the *Info* field is mapped correctly, so in the value *valueObject* i have the full object *Info*. But the string *This is a value* is not mapped, because JAXB library maps only the first field called "value".

What can I do to map the value string?

I found on StackOverflow one similar question, but in the response they said to use the object Node (DOM library). So, the field is treated as a String, and in a second moment they used another time the JAXB library to map the complex Object.
So, this is not a good solution for my script because I have a list of string and a list of object; then, if the list is very long I will have to read the list.

What can I do ? Can you help me ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't see how your `valueObject` could work for the second example, because the annotations show it's an element named `<value>` of type `Info`, which has an element named `<obj>` of type `String`. Nowhere is the element named `<info>` defined, so `<value> <info> <obj>obj1</obj> </info> </value>` should not be mapped, only `<value> <obj>obj1</obj> </value>` would be.

Comment: Since the `<value>` element can contain text content and/or element content, it needs to be defined as "mixed" content, and you'll have to process the mixed list yourself to get the text and/or object. See e.g. [How to deal with JAXB ComplexType with MixedContent data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12568247/5221149)