# Text field missing with XJC jaxb2-maven-plugin while generating HL7 CDA2 mixed complex types

Tags: glassfish, java-17, maven-jaxb2-plugin, cda

I'm facing a bad error when generating JAXB classes for parsing HL7 CDA2 documents ([here is the complete xsd definition](https://github.com/HL7/CDA-core-2.1/tree/master/schemas/normative)): the complex type **ANY** is generated without a String field annotaded as *@XmlValue* that contains the effective tag text, this results in having empty object when unmarshalling and truncated XML when re-marshalling. As an example this fragment of XML containing an address:

```
        <addr use="H">
            <country>123</country>
            <streetAddressLine>Streen Name, 1</streetAddressLine>
            <postalCode>12345</postalCode>
            <city>City Name</city>
        </addr>
```

will result in:

```
        <addr use="H">
            <country/>
            <streetAddressLine/>
            <postalCode/>
            <city/>
        </addr>
```

This is the XSD definition of the ANY complex type:

```
    <xs:complexType name="ANY" abstract="true">
        <xs:attribute name="nullFlavor" type="NullFlavor" use="optional">
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
```

This is the complete pom of the project with the plugin for generating classes with maven:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>xml.model.cda2</groupId>
    <artifactId>cda-jaxb-model</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
    </parent>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jaxb2-maven-plugin.version>3.1.0</jaxb2-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
    <profiles>
        <!-- Jaxb model generation profile
            https://github.com/HL7/CDA-core-2.1/tree/master/schemas/normative
        -->
        <profile>
            <id>jakarta-xml-bind-cda2</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>fse20-xml-cda2</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${jaxb2-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>xjc</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <extension>true</extension>
                            <xjbSources>
                                <xjbSource>src/main/resources/jaxb.binding-cda2.xjb</xjbSource>
                            </xjbSources>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/main/resources/xsd/CDA.xsd</source>
                            </sources>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/xml-bind</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Here follows my binding file, considering that *CDA.xsd* is under *resources/xsd* folder, all other xsd files are in *resource/xsd/coreschemas*, I also added the *generateMixedExtensions* option that is not working for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings version="3.0"
    xmlns:jxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xjc="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="xsd/CDA.xsd">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="xml.model.cda2" />
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:bindings
        schemaLocation="xsd/coreschemas/POCD_MT000040UV02.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings
            node="//xs:complexType[@name='POCD_MT000040UV02.ObservationMedia']/xs:attribute[@name='ID']">
            <jxb:property name="id2" />
        </jxb:bindings>
        <jxb:bindings
            node="//xs:complexType[@name='POCD_MT000040UV02.RegionOfInterest']/xs:attribute[@name='ID']">
            <jxb:property name="id2" />
        </jxb:bindings>
        <jxb:bindings
            node="//xs:complexType[@name='POCD_MT000040UV02.Section']/xs:attribute[@name='ID']">
            <jxb:property name="id2" />
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings
        xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="2.0"
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
        jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
        <jaxb:globalBindings
            generateMixedExtensions="true" />
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

At the moment I've solved with a manual patch adding to the class **ANY** a string field annotated with *@XmlValue* after xjc generation.

**EDIT/HINT:** starting from a suggestion of ChatGPT I discovered that the problem is a **limit of JAXB XJC tool** that is not able to process complex elements having *mixed="true"* property, the problem with this xsd deifning CDA documents was [already known in the far 2010 and was treated in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049067/jaxb-xjc-compiler-disregarding-mixed-true-on-xml-schema-documents), but unfortunately the solution provided in this thread doesen't work for me, probably due to the fact that I'm using Glassfish

Comment: Could you share your binding file please ?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your build but can't get anything generated and the only difference is your `<xjbSource>src/main/resources/jaxb.binding-cda2.xjb</xjbSource>` that I don't have. Thanks

Comment: I've added the binding file, consider that the problem comes because ANY is extended by "mixed" elements. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this answer will solve your problem since I don't have all your project input but there's a suggestion of update based on your inputs.

The following bindings.xjb file is updated to not mix JAXB3/JAXB2 bindings and add the `<jxb:globalBindings generateMixedExtensions="true" />` instruction.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings version="3.0"
    xmlns:jxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xjc="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">

    <jxb:globalBindings generateMixedExtensions="true" />

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="xsd/CDA.xsd">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="xml.model.cda2" />
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:bindings
        schemaLocation="xsd/POCD_MT000040UV02.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings
            node="//xs:complexType[@name='POCD_MT000040UV02.ObservationMedia']/xs:attribute[@name='ID']">
            <jxb:property name="id2" />
        </jxb:bindings>
        <jxb:bindings
            node="//xs:complexType[@name='POCD_MT000040UV02.RegionOfInterest']/xs:attribute[@name='ID']">
            <jxb:property name="id2" />
        </jxb:bindings>
        <jxb:bindings
            node="//xs:complexType[@name='POCD_MT000040UV02.Section']/xs:attribute[@name='ID']">
            <jxb:property name="id2" />
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

By adding this like this, the generated `BIN` class evolves from

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "BIN")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ED.class,
    EDR2B.class
})
public abstract class BIN
    extends ANY
{

    @XmlAttribute(name = "representation")
    protected BinaryDataEncoding representation;

    /**
     * Obtient la valeur de la propriété representation.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link BinaryDataEncoding }
     *     
     */
    public BinaryDataEncoding getRepresentation() {
        if (representation == null) {
            return BinaryDataEncoding.TXT;
        } else {
            return representation;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Définit la valeur de la propriété representation.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link BinaryDataEncoding }
     *     
     */
    public void setRepresentation(BinaryDataEncoding value) {
        this.representation = value;
    }

}
```

To the following with a new field `@XmlMixed protected List<Serializable> content;`

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "BIN", propOrder = {
    "content"
})
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ED.class,
    EDR2B.class
})
public abstract class BIN
    extends ANY
{

    @XmlMixed
    protected List<Serializable> content;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "representation")
    protected BinaryDataEncoding representation;

    /**
     * 
     *             Binary data is a raw block of bits. Binary data is a
     *             protected type that MUST not be used outside the data
     *             type specification.
     *          Gets the value of the content property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the Jakarta XML Binding object.
     * This is why there is not a {@code set} method for the content property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getContent().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link String }
     * 
     * 
     * @return
     *     The value of the content property.
     */
    public List<Serializable> getContent() {
        if (content == null) {
            content = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return this.content;
    }

    /**
     * Obtient la valeur de la propriété representation.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link BinaryDataEncoding }
     *     
     */
    public BinaryDataEncoding getRepresentation() {
        if (representation == null) {
            return BinaryDataEncoding.TXT;
        } else {
            return representation;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Définit la valeur de la propriété representation.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link BinaryDataEncoding }
     *     
     */
    public void setRepresentation(BinaryDataEncoding value) {
        this.representation = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes it worked, many many thanks.
I was one step away from solution because I added the global binding option in a nested tag and it was ignored. I've regenerated and tested, now the textual content of the tag is saved and avilable.

Comment: Glad it helped you. Don't forget to accept the answer :)